# How to track nested object creation

Tags: php, inheritance, nested, php-7

I have a parent class and multiple children that inherit from it.

Some children will call other children within themselves. But they are not always called nested.

```
class Parent { }

class Child extends Parent {
    public function run() {
        // Kid nested inside Child. Do not open DB transaction
        $a = (new Kid())->run();
    }
}

class Kid extends Parent {
    public function run() {
        // @todo Open DB transaction if not nested
    }
}

// Kid not nested. Open DB transaction
(new Kid())->run();
```

Is there an efficient way for the `Kid` object to know (without being manually told by me) whether it was instantiated inside or outside of `Child`?

Comment: Automatically? Probably not. Maybe if you explain what you are trying to achieve, we could help in another way...

Comment: @FirstOne I want the top level child class to open and close a DB transaction inside its `run` method. But as you can see in some cases `Kid` is top level and in other cases it is not

Comment: Well, you _could*_ try something with [$GLOBALS](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php). If the outter child is really out of everything, you can try and match to see: if what you have is the same as what you got from globals, that was created outside. **Edit:** note that this is not about setting the variable as global. It's about checking if the variable is there...

Comment: @FirstOne yeah I want to avoid globals. Only thing I can think of is parsing the stack trace (lol) or manually telling the object when it's nested. I will probably do the latter but just wanted to see if there was any new PHP7 magic that would help

Comment: I think you probably should be asking yourself "if you should" rather than "how to". This sounds like an architecture/design shortfall to me. Based on your explanatory comment (you should put that in your question, not in a comment, btw), I suspect you ought to be abstracting the DB activity out of Child and Kid completely, and have a DB adapter of some description which deals with the transactionality separately, irrespective of whether the call comes from a Kid or a Child. It would help answer the question emphatically if you updated it to be more real-world, rather than figurative.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing how your code is structured, the only way I could think of is to make two child classes (we'll call them `Kid1` and `Kid2`). All they would do is

```
class Kid1 extends Kid {}
```

Then you would call

```
class Child extends Parent {
    public function run() {
        // Kid nested inside Child. Do not open DB transaction
        $a = (new Kid1())->run();
    }
}

class Kid extends Parent {
    public function run() {
        // @todo Open DB transaction if not nested
        if($this instanceof Kid2) // Open DB
    }
}
```

Yes, you're still telling `Kid` what called it, but it fits with OOP practices

Answer (score 0):

Use `debug_backtrace` function to trace the `run` method calls.
Among all possible returned elements from `debug_backtrace()`, `class` item should be traced in your case.
If there's more than one `class` item within stack trace - it's a "nested" invocation:

```
class Parent { }

class Child extends Parent {
    public function run() {
        // Kid nested inside Child. Do not open DB transaction
        $a = (new Kid())->run();
    }
}

class Kid extends Parent {
    public function run() {
        $trace = debug_backtrace();
        // Note that 'array_column' function is available since PHP 5.5        
        if (count(array_column($trace, 'class')) > 1) {
            // Do not open DB transaction
            // do another job
        } else {
            // Open DB transaction
        }
        unset($trace);
    }
}

// Kid not nested. Open DB transaction
(new Kid())->run();

(new Child())->run(); // Kid nested inside Child. Do not open DB transaction
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

Comment: Tracing is expensive, not a good idea to trace for anything other than an exceptional code path.

Comment: @JoeWatkins, nevertheless, it will give the most accurate info